# Google MQTT broker - is IP address stable from mqtt.googleapis.com

Tags: mqtt, google-cloud-iot

The new NBIOT demo modules from O2 - we are testing - they only accept an IP address as a broker host rather than URL [mqtt.googleapis.com].  If i run DNS lookup this is fine - but how stable is the IP address associated with the mqtt.googleapis.com ??

I have the DNS lookup here 74.125.201.206

How long will it remain stable / the same ??

```
stream {
    upstream google_mqtt {
            server mqtt.googleapis.com:8883;
    }
    server {
            listen 8883;
            proxy_pass google_mqtt;
    }
}
```

Instead of the mqtt url i want to insert IP address

Comment: Why do you need an IP address specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to hard code the IP address? You are just setting yourself up for it to fail at the moment you can't fix it (e.g. while on vacation)

You shouldn't assume an IP address returned by a DNS query is good for any longer than the TTL value returned with the response.

Hostnames are a deliberate abstraction so you don't have to worry about if the IP address changes, be it due to a failure, maintenance, load balancing.

Just DON'T hardcode the IP address.

If the module you mentioned REALLY only accepts IP addresses then you need to raise a bug against the supplier saying this needs fixing, especially as this is for a field deployed device that you probably can't easily update once deployed.